# get count of items per category and insert into another table

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am struggling with an issue which I believe some of you will be quite easy to resolve.

I have two tables, one which holds items of cars objects with their respective categories, each car make has its own category.

The second table, holds the same list of categories and another column that should hold the total number of car items per category. e.g carCategory=30, TotalItems=6.

I was able to get the count statement running however i was unable to find the correct way to get the values from the count statement on the first table and place them on the second table in their respective category.

Any suggestions how can I solve this one?

Here are the tables 
"cars_for_sell" table:

```
+------+------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------+------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+-----------------+
| "id" |  "car_id"  | "car_vendor" | "car_model" | "car_petro" | "car_transmition" | "car_hand" | "car_spedometer" | "car_engine_vol" | "car_category" | "car_post_date" |
+------+------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------+------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+-----------------+
| "39" | "33333333" | "Mazda"      | "3"         | "Disel"     | "automatic"       | "3"        | "1111111"        | "1600"           | "30"           | "2/20/2002"     |
| "49" | "6666666"  | "Toyota"     | "Avensis"   | "Gasolin"   | "manual"          | "6"        | "2222222"        | "1800"           | "10"           | "8/12/2015"     |
+------+------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------+------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

"posts_per_category" table:

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+------------------+
| "category" |  "carMake"   | "NumOfPosts" | "LastUpdateDate" |
+------------+--------------+--------------+------------------+
| "10"       | "BMW"        | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "20"       | "MG"         | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "30"       | "AUDI"       | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "40"       | "OPEL"       | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "50"       | "ALFA_ROMEO" | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "60"       | "BUICK"      | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "70"       | "DACIA"      | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "80"       | "HONDA"      | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "90"       | "VOLVO"      | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "100"      | "TOYOTA"     | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "110"      | "HYUNDAI"    | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "120"      | "LANCIA"     | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "130"      | "MAZDA"      | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "140"      | "MITSUBISHI" | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "150"      | "NISSAN"     | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "160"      | "SUBARU"     | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "170"      | "SUZUKI"     | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "180"      | "SEAT"       | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "190"      | "CITROEN"    | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "200"      | "SKODA"      | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "210"      | "VOLKSWAGEN" | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "220"      | "FORD"       | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "230"      | "FIAT"       | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "240"      | "PEUGEOT"    | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "250"      | "KIA"        | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "260"      | "CHRYSLER"   | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "270"      | "RENAULT"    | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
| "280"      | "CHEVROLET"  | "0"          | "12/24/2015"     |
+------------+--------------+--------------+------------------+
```

Here is the result I am getting from count statement:

```
+----+---+
| 10 | 1 |
+----+---+
| 30 | 1 |
+----+---+
```

So once I have the result above I need that "posts_per_category" will have the updated results stored in "NumOfPosts" column according to their respective categories

Comment: I added relevant information, hope that clears the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you should do something like:

```
UPDATE posts_per_category ppc SET ppc.numOfPosts= (SELECT count(id) FROM cars_for_sell cfs WHERE ppc.category = cfs.car_category)
```

But I think that this method is not *right*. Maybe you should to think about using *triggers* (you can create "events" which will fire when new cars will be added and update ppc.NumOfPosts, for example).

Comment: Dude just tested it, and it is exactly what I wanted. Using the trigger is my next step, BTW do you know how can i extend this statement that will also update the "LastUpdateDate" in the updated row?

Comment: **If type of columns car_post_date and LastUpdateDate is Datetime**:
`UPDATE posts_per_category ppc SET ppc.numOfPosts= (SELECT count(id) FROM cars_for_sell cfs WHERE ppc.category = cfs.car_category), ppc.LastUpdateDate = (SELECT MAX(cars_for_sell.car_post_date) FROM cars_for_sell WHERE cars_for_sell.car_category = ppc.category)`
**If these columns are string**, you should use MAX(STR_TO_DATE(cars_for_sell.car_post_date)) instead MAX(cars_for_sell.car_post_date));

There is one more method: use MAX(cars_for_sell.id) instead MAX(cars_for_sell.car_post_date). But it is bad practice:)

Comment: Works like a charm! As i am still new to sql statements you saved me lots of time consuming research